# Alert in javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, alert

I don't know why the javascript doesn't work. The alert messages aren't displayed.  This is a simple html file to validate a form that is used to add a book to a database. On hitting the submit button, the page directs itself to the following links without diplaying the alert window.Please help me out.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Add Book</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/default.css" />
</head>
<body id="index_page">
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 align="left">Library</h1>
    </div> 
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="index"><a href="http://localhost/UID/FAQ.php">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main_content">
    <h2>Add book</h2>
  <h4>Enter details of the book</h4>
  <FORM action="add_book_action.php" method="post" >
   <TABLE WIDTH="50%" >

    <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book ID:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" name="id" id="book_id"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book Name:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" name="name" id="book_name"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book Author:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="author" id="book_author"></TD>
  </tr>  
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Year of Publication:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pub" id="book_year"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Submit" onclick="return   validate_fun()"></TD>
  </tr>
  </TABLE>
  </FORM>

  </div>
     <p id="footer"><a href="http://localhost/UID/UID.php">@AntonyAjay,2012</a></p>
    </div>


 <script language="javascript">
 function validate_fun()
 {
  var x=document.getElementById("book_id").value;
   if(x==""||isNaN(x))
{
alert("Book Id should be numeric");
return false;   
}
  var x=document.getElementById("book_name").value;
 var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
 if(!(regex.test(x)))
{
alert("Book Name should be only characters and spaces");
return false;   
}
  var x=document.getElementById("book_author").value;
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
  if(!(regex.test(x)))
{
alert("Author Name should be only characters and spaces");
return false;   
}
  }

  var x = document.getElementById("book_year").value;

  var regExp = /^([1][6-9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][01][0-9]\/|-([1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][01])\/|-([1-9]|[1][012])$/;

   if(!(regExp.test(x)))
   {
alert("Enter date in yyyy-mm-dd format");
return false;
   }
  }
 </script>
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Your code produces a `Syntax Error: unexpected token }`. Open your browser's debugging tools (F12 in most browsers), look at the errors it reports. (Edit: and learn to indent your code, or get an IDE that can do it for you. The error will be obvious.)

Comment: All your alerts are inside conditional, have you checked if the conditions ever become true? It could be a problem with your reflex or the data your using to test the page.

Comment: I am going to close as `too localised` since it's unlikely anyone will 1) encounter the same issue (syntax error) 2) under the same circumstances and 3) will not find it by debugging.

Comment: @JanDvorak: in my opinion, *all* `Syntax Error`s fall under "too localized".

Comment: Also "this question does not show any research effort", IMO

Comment: I rectified that error by removing the extra } next to one of the test cases but still the alert window isn't displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In additional to that extra `}`, your code lacks closing `<div #wrapper>`, also this RegExp has a pairless parenthese:

```
var regExp = /^([1][6-9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][01][0-9]\/|-([1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][01])\/|-([1-9]|[1][012])$/;
```

All these can be found in two seconds when using browser's Dev Tool...

Comment: ok, got the error rectified. It was the unmatched parenthesis in the regular expression that didn't allow the alert box to be displayed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone had suggested already please use the developer tools from any modern browser, it will be able to tell you a lot more. If you are still struggling, the modified code below, but these are silly errors so make sure you have an IDE which could do the indenting and checks for missing or extra braces.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title>Add Book</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/default.css" />
</head>
<body id="index_page">
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 align="left">Library</h1>
    </div> 
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li id="index"><a href="http://localhost/UID/FAQ.php">FAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="main_content">
    <h2>Add book</h2>
  <h4>Enter details of the book</h4>
  <FORM action="add_book_action.php" method="post" >
   <TABLE WIDTH="50%" >

    <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book ID:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" name="id" id="book_id"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book Name:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" name="name" id="book_name"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Book Author:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="author" id="book_author"></TD>
  </tr>  
  <TR>
      <TH width="50%">Year of Publication:</TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pub" id="book_year"></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TD width="50%"><INPUT TYPE="submit" Value="Submit" onclick="return   validate_fun()"></TD>
  </tr>
  </TABLE>
  </FORM>

  </div>
     <p id="footer"><a href="http://localhost/UID/UID.php">@AntonyAjay,2012</a></p>
    </div>


 <script language="javascript">
 function validate_fun()
 {
    var x=document.getElementById("book_id").value;
    if(x==""||isNaN(x))
    {
        alert("Book Id should be numeric");
        return false;   
    }
    var x=document.getElementById("book_name").value;
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    if(!(regex.test(x)))
    {
        alert("Book Name should be only characters and spaces");
        return false;   
    }
    var x=document.getElementById("book_author").value;
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
    if(!(regex.test(x)))
    {
        alert("Author Name should be only characters and spaces");
        return false;   
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("book_year").value;
    var regExp = /^([1][6-9][0-9][0-9]|[2][0][01][0-9]\/|-([1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][01])\/|-([1-9]|[1][012])$/;

    if(!(regExp.test(x)))
    {
        alert("Enter date in yyyy-mm-dd format");
        return false;
    }
  }
 </script>
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: hey....I copy-pasted the modified code.. I rectified the possible syntax error... It still is not able to display the alert box. I'm sorry to bother you much but it isnt working fine in my system.

Comment: I only corrected the syntax error, it works fine on chrome. I get an alert box when I do a submit without filling in form. Can you please tell me what you tried rather than just saying alert box isn't displayed?

Comment: Being a newbee to JS, I wrote this code on the default text editor in ubuntu. I hit the submit button and it connects to the database. No validation was done. I rectified this problem by adding the matching closing parenthesis as suggested by Teemu. It works perfectly now.